# Redirecting / Remapping / Pre-filtering cursor input from touch screen

Tags: c#, windows-7, touch, touchscreen, mouse-cursor

### MY PROBLEM

Okay, well the basic answer to this would be using the:

```
Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

But my problem is a bit more complicated.

What I need it to do is correctly map itself to a specific windows bounds so that the touch input will be restricted to that window, but will **properly clip itself to the window so that when I touch the top-left corner or the bottom-right corner of the touch screen, it will place the cursor to the top-left or bottom-right of the window.** Using `Cursor.Clip` will not do that and everything I touch on the touchscreen that outside of that clipping zone will just get mapped to it's closest edge of the window from where I am touching.

Is there anything that will allow me to pre-filter the mouse position so I can adjust it's bounds correctly?

### IF ALL ELSE FAILS

Alternatively, I could try to find some code that will convert the mouse feed into **TUIO** input and feed it into the application that way, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that. So if anyone knows of how I can do that, that would be helpful to if my original request is not possible.

### FOR THOSE WHO WANT TO KNOW EXACTLY WHAT I AM DOING

If you need to know exactly why I am doing this, I am basically trying to feed the mouse events from a touch screen being fed in video into a 3D application that can take in touch inputs (through normal mouse events or TUIO) that will draw to that video, but has no way of maximizing to the full resolution of the screen because it will only render the size it is set to output at.

### TO BE CLEAR

- I don't mind a normal mouse being disrupted by any of this.
- I am talking about a Windows 7 system using the default Windows 7 Touch
- The input is coming in via USB, not serial or anything like that.

Comment: could you put a transparent frame behind your rendered item and have the transparent frame be maximized?

Comment: If you already _have_ the location of the working area on the screen, then the problem is just of homography re-projection, do you have the bounds of the working area? If yes, I'll post my code and usage in the answers...

Answer (score 1):

You could use Reactive Extensions to clip the touch events

```
var movingEvents = 
      Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
        h => this.MouseMove += h, h => this.MouseMove -= h)
          .Select(x => x.EventArgs.Location)
          .Where(location =>
               location.X >= viewPort.Location.X 
                  && location.X <= viewPort.Location.X + viewPort.Width
                  && location.Y >= viewPort.Location.Y 
                  && location.Y <= viewPort.Location.Y + viewPort.Height);

movingEvents.Subscribe(update);

public void update(Point p)
{
    textBox1.Text = p.ToString();
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52308/The-Rx-Framework-By-Example

Comment: I don't think this is prefiltering though. It may appear to work on screen, but if the mouse at any point programmatically registers at another point, the drawing application will draw it. This still seems to depend the MouseMove event which occurs AFTER the mouse movement has taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a low-level mouse hook might work, since touch screens prior to Windows 8 usually try to masquerade as mice the best they can.

See for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C